# SecurityQuestion DropDownList - Predefined items

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I'm trying to make a drop drown during user registration for "Security Question".

Should the `SecurityQuestion` property on my ViewModel be a string (to hold only the selected question) or an `IEnumerable<string>` to hold the entire list of question? In the later case, how will the model POSTed know which was selected?

Depending on which is the better approach what will be the code to display the html drop down list and pre-select the top most item (this is a required field so a "blank" should not be selectable)?

Also, I'll be submitting this form using ajax. In the former case, I can use `option:selected` selector to append the selected question to the `string` SecurityQuestion property on my model. But I'm not understanding how it would work in the latter case (with an `IEnumerable<string>` as the property on the model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok figured this out. I used a string type to hold just the selected Security Question and Answer:

```
public class RegisterFormViewModel
{
    ...

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Security Question")]
    public string SecurityQuestion { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Security Answer")]
    public string SecurityAnswer { get; set; }

    ...  
}
```

Then populated the list like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SecurityQuestion, QuestionHelper.GetSecurityQuestions())
```

Using this helper:

```
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSecurityQuestions()
    {
        return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "What was your childhood nickname?", Text = "What was your childhood nickname?"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "What is the name of your favorite childhood friend?", Text = "What is the name of your favorite childhood friend?"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "What school did you attend for sixth grade?", Text = "What school did you attend for sixth grade?"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "In what city or town did your mother and father meet?", Text = "In what city or town did your mother and father meet?"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "What is the first name of the boy or girl that you first kissed?", Text = "What is the first name of the boy or girl that you first kissed?"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "What is the name of a college you applied to but didn't attend?", Text = "What is the name of a college you applied to but didn't attend?"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "Where were you when you first heard about 9/11?", Text = "Where were you when you first heard about 9/11?"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "What is your grandmother's first name?", Text = "What is your grandmother's first name?"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "What was the make and model of your first car?", Text = "What was the make and model of your first car?"},
                new SelectListItem { Value = "In what city and country do you want to retire?", Text = "In what city and country do you want to retire?"}
            };
    }
```

Then did an ajax post like this:

```
$.post('/Account/Register', $('#registerForm').serialize(), function(){ //success });
```

The jQuery serialize method sends the "Value" of the selected item for the security question. I wanted the actual question which is why i set Value and Text to the same thing, otherwise you can set it so whatever value you want to get if the item is selected.